# Grid vertically centering text CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a grid with four distinct quadrants. In each quadrant, I am looking to center the text vertically as well as horizontally. I have the text set horizontally but not vertically. Here is a picture of part of my grid.
[image: image of grid]

Here is my CSS that makes the grid:

```
.gridcontainer {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 100% 100%;
}
```

Here is what one of my grid contents looks like in CSS:

```
.logantitle {
    font-family: "angleultra";
    opacity: 0%;
    text-align: center;

}

.loganintro {
    font-family: "montserrat-regular";
    opacity: 0%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is pretty helpful for centering, I filled out what I believe is what you have

http://howtocenterincss.com/#contentType=div&content.width=100pct&content.height=100pct&container.width=100pct&container.height=100pct&horizontal=center&vertical=middle&browser.IE=none

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's recommended that you paste the relevant code too. Sometimes links break.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can can center text in modern browsers. Use `min-height: 100vh` instead if you want it to span the whole page.

```css
.center {
  margin: 0;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  hello world
</div>
```